# any multi-boot loader for linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, solaris, boot

Is there any multi-boot loader available for Linux(ubuntu) as primary OS? Because need to run Ubuntu, Solaris and Red-hat on same machine.

Answer (score 2):

[Grub2](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Since January 2006, Solaris 10 and newer releases bundle an enhanced grub that natively boot Solaris (not chainload). This grub can be used to boot Ubuntu, Red Hat and chainload any OS not supported by Grub like Windows or previous Solaris releases. You cannot directly use the Grub bundled with Gnu/Linux distributions to boot Solaris as they do not support booting ZFS (not sure about Solaris UFS).

AFAIK, Grub2 doesn't support booting Solaris, although it might support chainloading Solaris own boot loader.

Comment: Based on what you said, can't you chainload grub2 from solaris boot loader ? I mean

solarisBoot (solaris) --- chainload -- > Grub2 (ubuntu, redhat)

Comment: I'm not familiar yet with Grub2 but I'm quite sure what you describe should just work with it.

Comment: And here is a page describing precisely a way to do it: http://praveen.kumar.in/2010/02/20/chainloading-opensolaris-from-grub-2/

Answer (score 1):

GRUB is capable of booting [Solaris](http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/grub.html).